# What is the proper way of storing images for a chat service using sockets?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

Ok so I've looked everywhere and people seem to have mixed opinions about this. So I went ahead and just did it a way I thought was right, I'm having second thoughts now as I think storing a huge `base64` string in a mongodb database is ridiculous.

Here is a snippet of code to what I'm doing now:

```
var imgUploader;
   // Base64Img holds the base 64 value from the chosen file.
    if(base64Img != ""){

         // Send message to chat and save to mongo: 
          socket.emit('clientMessage', {
               message: $('#chatMessage').val(), 
               name: user.name,
               userId: user.userId,
               image : base64Img
          });
        $("#imgUpload").val("");
        base64Img = "";
        return;
}
```

I'm sending the `base64` along with other message data off to the server using `sockets.io` and `node`, so It can be saved to a `mongoDB`, and then emitted back to other chat users. Once other users get that data back, I simply append the `base64` value to an `<img />` html tag

#### Possible options:

1. Store `Image` in a folder on the server and then save link to the image in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be good idea to store image on folder on server, instead of Base64 string and/or in DB.

Good way to store image in Amazon s3 storage with cloudfront.

Comment: Ok! Any idea how I can send the image file via sockets? (If it's possible)

Comment: by the way, if I am not mistaken, you could then just send a direct link to image on s3.

Comment: Yes, Upload image on s3, once completed send url to another user or server

Answer (score 0):

**Dont store image in DB**

You store only a link to that image in DB.

*Your options:*

- You can convert your base64 back to image and save in on disk.
- Or, instead of sending image in base64 encoding which increased size by around 20-30% percent.
  you can use separate http method to send image to server and save it there.
  that method will return you a link to that image, which in turn you will send using websockets with you message.

Also instead of saving images on your server you can use services like Amazon S3, Google Storage or a handful of others where you can save your image.

But either way, you should only keep a link in your DB.